# How to filter by grand parent value when deleting multiple child objects in realm?

Tags: swift, filter, realm

I'm trying to delete all WSR objects that are associated with all Exercise objects within a particular workout object.

I just have some trouble filtering out all the WSR objects. The way it's set up right now, if I have multiple Exercise objects, only the WSR values associated with the first Exercise object get deleted, but not the rest.

How could I filter out all WSR objects that are associated with all Exercise objects within a particular workout?

```
class Days : Object {
    @objc dynamic var weekday : String = ""

    let workout = List<Workouts>()
}

class Workouts : Object {
    @objc dynamic var title : String = ""
    var parentDay = LinkingObjects(fromType: Days.self, property: "workout")

    let exercise = List<Exercises>()
}

class Exercises : Object {
    @objc dynamic var exerciseName : String = ""

    var parentWorkout = LinkingObjects(fromType: Workouts.self, property: "exercise")

    let wsr = List<WeightSetsReps>()
}

class WeightSetsReps : Object {
    @objc dynamic var weight = 0
    @objc dynamic var reps = 0
    var parentExercise = LinkingObjects(fromType: Exercises.self, property: "wsr")
}

if days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row].exercise.isEmpty == false {

    if let selectedWorkout = days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row] {
        let thisWorkoutsExercises = realm.objects(Exercises.self).filter("ANY parentWorkout == %@", selectedWorkout)
        // Filter function to get all wsr's associated with the selected workout...
        let thisWorkoutsWsr = realm.objects(WeightSetsReps.self).filter("ANY parentExercise == %@", days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row].exercise[indexPath.row])

        realm.delete(thisWorkoutsWsr)
        realm.delete(thisWorkoutsExercises)
        realm.delete((days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row])!)
    }
} else {
    realm.delete((days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row])!)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:
`let thisWorkoutsWsr = realm.objects(WeightSetsReps.self).filter("ANY parentExercise == %@", days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row].exercise[indexPath.row])`

By using `ANY parentExercise == ... .exercise[indexPath.row])` you request only WSRs from exercise at one index. Imho this could even crash, if this workouts exercise count is lower than the days workout count.
By using the `ANY .. IN ..` operator, you request all exercises in the `exercise` array.

Try this:

```
    guard let workout = days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row] else { return }
    if workout.exercise.isEmpty {  
        realm.delete(workout)
        return
    }


    let thisWorkoutsExercises = realm.objects(Exercises.self).filter("ANY parentWorkout == %@", workout)
    // Filter function to get all wsr's associated with the selected workout...
    let thisWorkoutsWsr = realm.objects(WeightSetsReps.self).filter("ANY parentExercise IN %@", thisWorkoutsExercises)

    realm.delete(thisWorkoutsWsr)
    realm.delete(thisWorkoutsExercises)
    realm.delete(workout)
```